# I'm getting a blank page from edits, but no one else is

Tags: blank-screen

I'm using an ancient form of Expression Engine on my site Comics Reporter.

Recently when I've gone to the control page and signed in

[image: the page of the site that i go to after signing in]

And then hit edit, I get this:

[image: a blank page]

I get this from four browsers: chrome, firefox, explorer (mac), safari; I get it after I clear cache although for a while that would bring the edit list back. It's been happening intermittently for about a month. But now there's no getting back to the edits page (by switching browsers or clearing cache).

I get this on my phone (wi-fi and 4G) and I get this on my laptop using this wi-fi.

Nobody else signing on remotely gets this. Ever.

My server people have checked if my IP is blocked and don't think it's on their end.

Any clue what might be getting in the way? Help? Thanks in advance if anyone can; last time I had a problem people just laughed at the fact I was using this old version and told me to go away!

Comment: How ancient is ancient? And what field type add-ons do you have in use?

Comment: Also, turn php error reporting on for all users for like, a second, and during that second, reload your WSOD entry form. Then your white screen should turn into a bunch of errors.

Comment: it is [drumroll] 1.4.1 and I don't know what a field type add-on is... let me see if I can do what you want from that one page i can get to load!

Comment: yeah, sorry, I honestly don't know how to do either of those things! thank you, though!

Comment: White screens are suppressed PHP errors 99.9% of the time. You say no one else sees this... Are they editing the exact entry you are trying to edit when you're testing? Are the people testing all set up as super admin users? Are you a super admin user?